# Angular 4, Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StateObservable: (?)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, http, karma-jasmine

i am writing unit test on one of my service. I am keep getting Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StateObservable: (?). and my test is failing.
can anyone tell me what is the issue?

**spec file code**

```
fdescribe("Physician Service", () => {
let physicianService: PhysicianService;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
let backend: MockBackend;
let initialResponse: any;

beforeEach(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Http,
    ConnectionBackend,
    UtilService,
    StateObservable,
    RouterModule,
    SessionService,
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    MockBackend,
    PhysicianService,
    AuthService,
    BrowserXhr,
    XHRBackend,
    Store,
    {
      deps: [
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions
      ],
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
      }
    }
  ],
  schemas:[
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
  });
 });

 fit("Should Create Physicians Service",
  inject([PhysicianService], (physicianService: PhysicianService) => {
    expect(physicianService).toBeTruthy();
    }));

 });
```

can anyone help me in this regard
Thanks

Comment: Can you share which parameter is the one's that can't be resolved on StateObservable? (Sharing the constructor of StateObservable for example)

Comment: that is the problem actually. i cant understand which parameters it is referring to. i am only using Observable<any> or model name in service

Comment: Can you share all the code of StateObservable?

Comment: which code? i just imported it in provider

Comment: @usmansaleem did you find any solution to this issue

Comment: yes @MohanGopi it was because of store and HttpClientTestingModule 
i removed store, stateObservable from providers and HttpClientTestingModule and added StoreModule.forRoot({}) in imports 
it solved my issue. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This should have an actual answer instead of being in the comments.

In the TestBed.configureTestingModule imports add StoreModule.forRoot({})

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      ...
      StoreModule.forRoot({})
    ],
    providers: [
      ...
    ]
  });
```